# re-expressing a simple operation as a function in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to construct a new variable, z, using two pre-existing variables -  x and y.  Suppose for simplicity that there are only 5 observations (corresponding to 5 time periods) and that x=c(5,7,9,10,14) and y=c(0,2,1,2,3). I’m really only using the first observation in x as the initial value, and then constructing the new variable z using depreciated values of x[1] (depreciation rate of 0.05 per annum) and each of the observations over time in the vector, y. The variable I am constructing takes the form of a new 5 by 1 vector, z, and it can be obtained using the following simple commands in R:

```
z=NULL
for(i in 1:length(x)){n=seq(1,i,by=1)
z[i]=sum(c(0.95^(i-1)*x[1],0.95^(i-n)*y[n]))}
```

The problem I am having is that I need to define this operation as a function. That is, I need to create a function f that will spit out the vector z whenever any arbitrary vectors x and y are plugged into the function, f(x,y). I’ve been going around in circles for days now and I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to provide me with a suggestion about how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note, it's good form to upvote answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @HongOoi This user doesn't have enough reputation on the site to upvote yet. But he can accept an answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer he feels best answers his question.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware of this. I just opened my account and this is the first question I've ever posted, so I am still gaining familiarity with the protocol on this forum. I am thoroughly impressed with the quality of everyone's responses to my question though! Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope following will work for you...

```
x=c(5,7,9,10,14) 
y=c(0,2,1,2,3)

getZ = function(x,y){
  z = NULL
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    n=seq(1,i,by=1)
    z[i]=sum(c(0.95^(i-1)*x[1],0.95^(i-n)*y[n]))
  }
  return = z
}

z = getZ(x,y)
z
5.000000  6.750000  7.412500  9.041875 11.589781
```

Comment: @Larry There are 4 answer for you listed here... It would be great if you mark one of them as answer, or upvote which are helpful.. That will get this question out of unanswered list...

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I've posted a question on this forum. I didn't know this was required. I will make sure to follow your suggestion in the future. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This will allow .05 (or any other value) passed in as `r`.

```
ConstructZ <- function(x, y, r){
  n <- length(y)
  d <- 1 - r
  Z <- vector(length = n)
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    n = seq_len(i)
    Z[i] = sum(c(d^(i-1)*x[1],d^(i-n)*y[n]))
  }
 return(Z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cool (if I say so myself) way to implement this as an `infix` operator (since you called it an operation).

```
ff = function (x, y, i) {
       n = seq.int(i)
       sum(c(0.95 ^ (i - 1) * x[[1]],
             0.95 ^ (i - n) * y[n]))
}
`%dep%` = function (x, y) sapply(seq_along(x), ff, x=x, y=y)

x %dep% y
[1]  5.000000  6.750000  7.412500  9.041875 11.589781
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing the loop multiple times and recalculating the exponents every time may be inefficient. Here's another way to implement your calculation

```
getval <- function(x,y,lambda=.95) {
    n <- length(y)
    pp <- lambda^(1:n-1)
    yy <- sapply(1:n, function(i) {
        sum(y * c(pp[i:1], rep.int(0, n-i)))
    })
    pp*x[1] + yy
}
```

Testing with @vrajs5's sample data

```
x=c(5,7,9,10,14) 
y=c(0,2,1,2,3)
getval(x,y)

# [1]  5.000000  6.750000  7.412500  9.041875 11.589781
```

but appears to be about 10x faster when testing on larger data such as

```
set.seed(15)
x <- rpois(200,20)
y <- rpois(200,20)
```

I'm not sure of how often you will run this or on what size of data so perhaps efficiency isn't a concern for you. I guess readability is often more important long-term for maintenance.